# Series of a hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

Let $n>2$ be odd, and let $x\in [0,1]$. I would like to calculate the Taylor expansion of 
$$
x^{2-n} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{n}{2}-1,-n;2-\frac{n}{2};x^2\right)
$$ 
at $x=1$ leaving $n$ non specified. However, I get inconsistent results with Series. For instance, consider the minimal example in which the value of $\textrm{Hypergeometric2F1}[- 5/2, -3, -5, 1]$ is calculated

```
Hypergeometric2F1[-1 - n/2, -n, -n - 2, x] /. n -> 3 /. x -> 1
```

which gives $\frac{1}{32}$, while

```
Series[  Hypergeometric2F1[-1 - n/2, -n, -n - 2, (1 - z)], {z, 0, 
   0}] /. n -> 3
```

gives $\frac{3 \sqrt{z}}{16}$ which for $z=0$ vanishes.

Do you have any suggestion on how to correct this behavior and on how to solve my original problem?

Comment: That's very strange. 2F1 with a negative integer in the first group is a polynomial. Your example is (32 - 48 x + 18 x^2 - x^3)/32, or (1 + 15 z + 15 z^2 + z^3)/32.

Comment: @The Vee, yes, in general, hypergeometric functions whose numerator parameters are nonpositive integers degenerate to a polynomial, since some of the associated Pochhammer symbols in the series expansion become zero.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry for a misleading wording. I meant the behaviour of `Series` was strange because the reduction to a polynomial is so obvious.

Comment: Anyway: `Sum[(n (n^2 - 4) (-1)^k Binomial[n, k] x^(2 k - n + 2))/(n (n^2 - 4) + 4 k^2 (3 n - 2 k) - k (6 n^2 - 8)), {k, 0, n}]`, is prolly the series you want, but I derived that without using *Mathematica*.

Comment: @J.M., Thanks. It looks like a Laurent expansion at x=0. I was looking for the expansion at $x=1$.

Comment: Yes, apparently you did say that, but proceeded to give examples of expanding at $0$, which confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized I did not answer what the OP was asking in my earlier answer. That was the reason for the misbehaviour, here's the solution to the problem:

The solution can be obtained in a piecewise format: the coefficient at $(x-1)^l$ is
$$\alpha_l = \begin{cases}
a_l + b_l & l ≤ n+2\ \mbox{and even}, \\
a_l + c_l & l ≤ n+2\ \mbox{and odd}, \\
a_l & \mbox{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
a_l &= (-1)^l {n+l-3 \choose l} {_3F_2}\left(-1-\frac n2, -n, -\frac{n-3}2;\ -\frac{n-3+l}2, -\frac{n-4+l}2;\ 1\right), \\
b_l &= \frac{\left(-1-\frac n2\right)_{\tilde l} (-n)_{\tilde l} (l+1)}{(2-n)_{\tilde l} \tilde l!} {_3F_2}\left(-1-\frac n2+\tilde l, -n+\tilde l, -\frac{n-3}2+\tilde l;\ 1+\tilde l, \frac32;\ 1\right), \\
c_l &= \frac{\left(-1-\frac n2\right)_{\tilde l} (-n)_{\tilde l}}{(2-n)_{\tilde l} \tilde l!} {_3F_2}\left(-1-\frac n2+\tilde l, -n+\tilde l, -\frac{n-3}2+\tilde l;\ 1+\tilde l, \frac12;\ 1\right), \\
\tilde l &= \lfloor(l+n-1)/2\rfloor.
\end{aligned}$$
Note that the formulas for $b_l$ and $c_l$ differ in one of the denominator arguments and in a prefactor. All the $_3F_2$'s involved have a finite number of terms as both $-n$ and $-n+\tilde l$ are guaranteed to be nonpositive integers ($\tilde l \le n$).

This was obtained by an explicit expansion of the hypergeometric function
$$x^{2-n} {_2F_1}\left(-1-\frac n2, -n;\ 2-\frac n2;\ x^2\right)$$
in $x = 1+z$, using the generalized binomial theorem on $(1+z)^{2-n+2m}$, and extracting the coefficient for $z^l$ by hand. I then separated the cases where the Pochhammer symbol resulting from the latter step was zero, where it was a product of negative numbers only and positive numbers only. (Equivalently, the cases of positive and negative powers of $(1+z)$.) Mathematica then helped simplify the resulting sum over $m$. Unfortunately this is one of the cases where I found doing most of the work easier than trying to convince MMA of using all the assumptions correctly and at a proper time. Even trying to simplify the above piecewise expression brings in new trouble (namely introducing `Indeterminate`s from cases of `0*ComplexIninifty`).

I can't guarantee there's no typo in the above. Here's MMA code that should do the same:

```
With[{n = 7}, Table[
  (-1)^l*Binomial[n + l - 3, l]*
    HypergeometricPFQ[
     {-1 - n/2, -(n - 3)/2, -n},
     {-(n - 3 + l)/2, -(n - 4 + l)/2},
     1]
   + If[l > n + 2, 0,
    Pochhammer[-1 - n/2, ll]*Pochhammer[-n, ll]*
      If[EvenQ[l], l + 1, 1]/Pochhammer[2 - n/2, ll]/ll!*
      HypergeometricPFQ[
       {-1 - n/2 + ll, -n + ll, -(n - 3)/2 + ll},
       {ll + 1, If[EvenQ[l], 3/2, 1/2]},
       1] /. ll -> Floor[(l + n - 1)/2]
    ], {l, 0, 20}]]
CoefficientList[Series[
  With[{n = 7}, (1 + x)^(2 - n)*
    Hypergeometric2F1[-1 - n/2, -n, 2 - n/2, (x + 1)^2]],
  {x, 0, 20}], x]
% == %%
```

> {8192, 16384, 15360, 7168, 1792, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, -168, 350, -616, 981, -1461, 2073, -2835, 3766, -4886, 6216}
>
> {8192, 16384, 15360, 7168, 1792, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, -168, 350, -616, 981, -1461, 2073, -2835, 3766, -4886, 6216}
>
> True

Comment: Nicely done. It probably should be noted that the hypergeometric functions that show up in the coefficients are in fact polynomial cases as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem of genericity. The output of the command `Series[ Hypergeometric2F1[-1 - n/2, -n, -n - 2, (1 - z)], {z, 0, 0}]` (prior to substituting for $n$) is valid for almost all real values of $n$ but fails for those which are integer. The reason is that the hypergeometric function changes behaviour in these:

```
hg = Hypergeometric2F1[-1 - n/2, -n, -n - 2, (1 - z)];
Plot[Evaluate@Table[hg, {n, 2.94, 3.06, 0.02}], {z, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

I'm looking for a reference explaining this behaviour, I'll put it here when I have one.

**Edit**: Not entirely sure but I think it's using [this reduction](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/06/01/02/01/0005/) which has its validity restricted to $c \not\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this question morphs from asking about `Hypergeometric2F1[-1 - n/2, -n, 2-n/2, z]` to `Hypergeometric2F1[-1 - n/2, -n, -n-2, z]`? I'd expect the *former* is correct and, if so, you can use one of the [functional identities](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/02/09/0001/) (easily turned into a replacement rule) to obtain the series you are after:

```
x^(2-n) Hypergeometric2F1[-n/2-1,-n,2-n/2,x^2]/.
Hypergeometric2F1[a_,b_,c_,z_]:> Gamma[c-a-b] Gamma[c]*
Hypergeometric2F1[a,b,a+b+1-c,1-z]/(Gamma[c-a] Gamma[c-b])+
Gamma[a+b-c] Gamma[c] (1-z)^(c-a-b)*
Hypergeometric2F1[c-a,c-b,c+1-a-b,1-z]/(Gamma[a] Gamma[b])//FullSimplify
```

followed by

```
Series[%, {x, 1, 3}]
```

The leading term in the expansion is $\frac{2^{n+1} \Gamma \left(2-\frac{n}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$. Amusingly, the value of the alternative hypergeometric at $x=1$ is the reciprocal of this expression!

BTW, the *correct* expansion coefficients for $n=7$ are as follows:

```
{8192, 16384, 15360, 7168, 1792, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 112, -336, 700, 
 -1232, 1962, -2922, 4146, -5670, 7532, -9772, 12432}
```